# Indexing while using pandas loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pd.DataFrame which had a Datetime index. When I select a particular Datetime  and when there are two matches, it correctly selects date as the index.

```
a = df.loc[date]
a
```

```
           Symbol Order  Shares
Date                           
2011-01-10   AAPL   BUY    1500
2011-01-10   AAPL  SELL    1500
```

However, when there is only one match for that date, it assigns the columns as the index.

```
orders
Symbol    GOOG
Order      BUY
Shares    1000
Name: 2011-01-26 00:00:00, dtype: object
```

How can I force it to take Date as the index all the time? I don't have a name for the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one element list:

```
a = df.loc[[date]]
```

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
         Symbol Order  Shares
Date                           
2011-01-09   AAPL   BUY    1500
2011-01-10   AAPL   BUY    1500
2011-01-10   AAPL  SELL    1500

date = '2011-01-09'
a = df.loc[[date]]
print (a)
           Symbol Order  Shares
Date                           
2011-01-09   AAPL   BUY    1500

date = '2011-01-10'
a = df.loc[[date]]
print (a)
           Symbol Order  Shares
Date                           
2011-01-10   AAPL   BUY    1500
2011-01-10   AAPL  SELL    1500
```

Comment: To add some background on this answer: when `loc` matches a single row of the `DataFrame`, a `Series` is returned. The `Series` returned by the single-match `loc` has an `index` matching the DataFrame's `columns`, while the DataFrame's `index` becomes the `name` of the Series. The proposed answer always produces a `DataFrame` by indexing with a list.